# is it possible to list each category as a heading and its own products in a single sql query

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel, database

i have a DB schema as shown in the picture bellow : [image]

i want to view each category and subcategory as a heading  and list the products under it

note: the products must be of the same supplier

like this:

**category1**

- subcategory1

  ++product1

  ++product2
- subcategory2

  ++product1

  ++product2

**category2**

- subcategory

  ++product1

  ++product2

and is it possible to send this from controller to view in laravel ?

Comment: why is subcategory its own table?  and yes you can load the relationship and then iterate the categories, then each subcategory then the products for each subcategory

Comment: @lagbox what's wrong with making subcategory its own table ?

Comment: because a subcategory is just a category with a parent, but that isn't the issue here

Comment: so is it better to add parent_id to category table to refer to a category id ? i know its not the issue but i want to improve  my schema

Comment: Something like that https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=g6A_4_yuB-A ??